# Creating Microservices in ATG 10.2

Tags: microservices, atg

As part of requirements, there is an expectation to create microservices for an existing ecommerce platform. The current architecture runs on ATG 10.2 version and has some rest API's hosted on it.

Given the fact that ATG is a monolithic ecommerce framework, is there any way that we can create microservices in ATG? Even if we are able to do so, how will they run as independent services? i mean how can we deploy them and test them in other environment? Wanted to know the technical feasibility of creating microservices on ATG ecommerce platform.

Comment: Try upgrading to 11.3 which has Jersey Rest Webservices. I am voting to close this question as too broad.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need to define how your microservices are supposed to work first. If you were to, for example, expose the ATG `Profile` as a microservice, it won't, by itself, run in another environment, it simply means that you can expose the functionality for consumption by a different system via the service. Alternatively you can expose a `Profile` module on a different system and try to consume it within ATG. That too is possible.

In a nutshell you can integrate various open source libraries into your ATG stack to build and expose the functionality of the *monolithic* application into microservices. To get started, read up about `webmvc`, `oxm`, `hateoas`, `plugin-core`, `springtonucleus` and perhaps `dozer`.

Perhaps you need to define your architecture first before asking a much more specific question here. The real answer is just too long.